# How to write a file for a program's file argument in one line

Tags: command-line, bash, pipe, echo

I have a program that can accept, as an argument, a file full of commands and run them:

`$ <program> <filename>`

This is what I have working so far:

```
$ cat <filename>
<command>
$ <program> <filename>
<output indicating the command has been executed correctly>
```

However, I only need to run one command in this non-interactive mode, and do not want an extra file sitting around with only one command in it. I have tried piping the output of echo:

`$ <program> | echo "<command>"`

but this only gives the output:

`<command>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong; my pipe was backwards. I needed to do:

```
$ echo "<command>" | <program>
<output indicating the command has been executed correctly>
```

Note to self: pipes flow left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that might work ...

check.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
  echo "Ok"
else
  echo "Error"
fi
```

In console:

```
# command | check.sh
```

Example:

```
# ls | ./check.sh 
Ok
```